# Click and drag to scroll with mouse, React Typescript Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a reusable React component that will allow me to scroll horizontally using a mouse by clicking and dragging left and right, just as you would do with a trackpad or any tactil screen.

**Expected behavior:**
Div should scroll right and left following mouse drag

**Obtained behavior:**
Click and drag doesn't scroll. But having the mouse over the Div in reference and moving it sideways will scroll the div, to an extent.

I've tried so many ideas but I'm still enable to make it work.

I have tried multiple ways of making it work.. trying to tweak with the scroll bar (doesn't seem possible) with and without eventListeners... But overall I would say that my code could work with some adjustments.

I'm trying to adapt this working example for my react Component:
[Example that works but not with React](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/drag-to-scroll-a-simple-way-to-scroll-sideways-on-desktop/3627)

I'm creating a Draggable component that will wrap any div from the app that has horizontal overflow from the view. The logic of targeting the child div from Draggable is fine (using useRef)

Here's a code Pen reproducing where i'm at: [Code Pen with my code](https://codepen.io/hamiltons8/pen/qBMLmYR)

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useState, ReactNode, useRef, RefObject, useEffect } from "react";

type DraggableProps = {
  innerRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  rootClass: string;
  children: ReactNode;
};

export const Draggable = ({ innerRef, rootClass = "", children }: DraggableProps) => {
  const slider = innerRef.current as HTMLElement;
  const ourRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [pageX, setPageX] = useState(0);
  const [scrollX, setScrollX] = useState(0);
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleMouseDown()
  },[isScrolling])

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
      setIsScrolling(true);
    slider?.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      console.log("Mouse down => event", e);
      setPageX(e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft);
      setScrollX(slider?.scrollLeft);
    });
    slider?.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      console.log("Mouse leave");
      slider.removeEventListener("mousedown", () => {console.log("remove mouse down");
      });
      slider.removeEventListener("mousemove", () => {console.log("remove mouse move");
      });
      setIsScrolling(false);
    });
    slider?.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      console.log("Mouse up");
      slider.removeEventListener("mousedown", () => {console.log("remove mouse down");
      });
      slider.removeEventListener("mousemove", () => {console.log("remove mouse move");
      });
      setIsScrolling(false);
    });
    slider?.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (!isScrolling) return;
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Mouse move => pageX", pageX);

      const x = e.pageX - slider?.offsetLeft;
      const walk = x - pageX;
      slider.scrollLeft = scrollX - walk;
    });  
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ourRef} onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} className={rootClass}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I was doing something really simillar 2 days ago, you can take a look [here](https://github.com/The-Zagy/project-t/blob/master/apps/nextjs/src/pages/editor/index.tsx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const Draggable = ({rootClass = "", children }) => {
  const ourRef = useRef(null);
    const [isMouseDown, setIsMouseDown] = useState(false);
    const mouseCoords = useRef({
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        scrollLeft: 0,
        scrollTop: 0
    });
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
    const handleDragStart = (e) => {
        if (!ourRef.current) return
      const slider = ourRef.current.children[0];
        const startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        const startY = e.pageY - slider.offsetTop;
        const scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
        const scrollTop = slider.scrollTop;
        mouseCoords.current = { startX, startY, scrollLeft, scrollTop }
        setIsMouseDown(true)
        document.body.style.cursor = "grabbing"
    }
    const handleDragEnd = () => {
        setIsMouseDown(false)
        if (!ourRef.current) return
        document.body.style.cursor = "default"
    }
    const handleDrag = (e) => {
        if (!isMouseDown || ! ourRef.current) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        const slider = ourRef.current.children[0];
        const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
        const y = e.pageY - slider.offsetTop;
        const walkX = (x - mouseCoords.current.startX) * 1.5;
        const walkY = (y - mouseCoords.current.startY) * 1.5;
        slider.scrollLeft = mouseCoords.current.scrollLeft - walkX;
        slider.scrollTop = mouseCoords.current.scrollTop - walkY;
        console.log(walkX, walkY)
    }

  return (
    <div ref={ourRef} onMouseDown={handleDragStart} onMouseUp={handleDragEnd} onMouseMove={handleDrag} className={rootClass + "flex overflow-x-scroll"}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've modified your code to a working version which you can find here
https://codepen.io/sandstone991/pen/vYzvZNa

Comment: Wow that was quick, thank you, works like a charm!
I removed the vertical elements of your code as it's not relevant in my case.
There's just one side effect I'd like to get ride of, if you start dragging from an image to outside of the Div, as soon as you go out of the box, the image is dragged as well. 
How could i extend the e.preventDefault() to continue as long as the handleDrag (or isMouseDown) is true, even if it outside of the div?

Comment: solved, I added draggable={false} to my <img/> ! thanks again :)

Comment: @HamiltonS you're welcome <3